# HTML form, Google spreasheet and PHP confirmation page conflict

Tags: php, html, forms

I have and HTML form, a Google Spreadsheet and a PHP confirmation page. The form sends data to the sheet and after 'submit' it returns a confirmation page that reproduces the information the user gave. Both steps work fine separately but I can't make them work together.
So this is the HTML code for the form:

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet" action="conf.php" method="post">
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required><br>
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="name"><br>
<input name="apple" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> Manzana<br>
<input name="orange" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> Naranja<br>
<input name="banana" type="checkbox" value="Yes"> Banana<br>
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
<p id="response_message"></p>
</form>
```

This is the script that proves sending data to the sheet correctly. It also triggers the confirmation page, though its spaces left to provided data come blank:

```
      const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxJ9yXSrqqJCy82PV2eaIuNdfoLRWiayrBG1MT96n_av991Fuk/exec'
      const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

      form.addEventListener('submit', e => { 
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch(scriptURL, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new FormData(form)
              })
              .then(response => {
                  console.log('Success!', response );
                  window.location.href = "conf.php";
                }
              )
              .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
                      })
```

However, if I turned `window.location.href = "conf.php";` into `function () {window.location.href = "conf.php";}` confirmation page is correct with expected information but the form does not populate the spreadsheet. I can set this function in multiple lines and the effect is the same.

This is the relevant code of the confirmation page, by the way:

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES.utf-8");
    echo 'Name: ' . $_POST ["name"] . '<br>';
    echo 'E-mail: ' . $_POST ["email"] . '<br><br>';
    echo 'You chose:' . '<br>';
    echo 'Apple: ' . $_POST ["apple"] . '<br>';
    echo 'Orange: ' . $_POST ["orange"] . '<br>';
    echo 'Banana: ' . $_POST ["banana"] . '<br>';
    echo strftime("Submition date: %A %e de %B de %Y a %H:%M") . '<br>';
    ?>
```

What's my mistake? Thanks very mucn in advance.

Pd: this question is almost [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60390333/html-form-to-google-spreadsheet) I made recently but it seems to have died with a couple of answers but no solution. Maybe I was not clear myself. Thanks very much for that assistance anyway.